# A query tool for searching on projects in github

Tags: search, github

I am looking for an advanced query tool for github. the advanced search of github is not enough since it does not let you search for examples like this:

give me all projects that use a library such as qunit and have at least 100 closed issues.

Answer (score 0):

Such an advanced search could only use the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/).

However, none of the [Issue API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) exposes closed issue for *all* repos.
It only find closed issues for a specific repo or a specific user, which means you would have first to list *all* repos, and then make a query for each one.

SO right now, the search is still a work in progress, and has seen many improvement in 2013 (see "[Search code inside a Github project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616221/search-code-inside-a-github-project/3616259#3616259)"), but it isn't yet at the level you are after.