# Searching for -> on Github

Tags: github

How do I escape the `>` so I can search for all instances of `->` in a github repository?

I have attempted using `"->"` but that still sees the `>` as an operator. Is there an escape character I can add so that the search will work?

Comment: Has anyone figured this one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub search is [based on elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616259/6309), which has [reserved characters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) than you can escape.

'`>`' and '`<`' are [optional operators](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators) used for intervals, and it doesn't seem for that character to be escaped (in the way GitHub is using or has configured ealasticsearch).