# How to search for && as raw text in github

Tags: search, github, escaping, ampersand

I'd like to search for code inside a github repository, which contains lines like this :

```
echo a && echo b
```

I'm trying to search `&&` inside that repository, but I've got an error message :

> **We could not perform this search**
>
> The search contains only logical
>   operators (AND / OR / NOT) without any search terms.

I can't manage to escape these ampersands. There is no match found, neither with `\&\&` nor `'&&'` nor `"&&"`.

How can I perform that search ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22422651/6309), the [GitHub help page has been updated](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/).
It does not seem possible:

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query:

```
. , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ].
```

> The search will simply ignore these symbols.

So escaping (`\&`) or even `&amp;` don't work, because they include symbols which are ignored by the search query.