# How to search on GitHub to get exact string matches, including special characters

Tags: search, github

I can search exact matches from Google by using quotes like `"system <<-"`.

How can I do the same thing for GitHub?

Comment: @Machavity, thank you for the editing! When I was asking this question, my English was still very poor. But now my English is much better. Looking back at the questions I asked back then, I feel ashamed... Thanks for making it better!

Comment: You cannot search for exact matches on Google for a loooooong time now ...

Comment: @sdbbs Oh, I just tried and it's true! When did this start? Too bad.

Comment: This is getting a bit off-topic, but Google's verbatim mode (under "search tools" on the search result page) does exact matches...

Comment: @Justalearner is your update out-of-date? I get redirected to github.com when I try to visit the new GitHub code search page: https://cs.github.com/

Comment: @KevinLeStarge I just tried and it still works.

Comment: @Justalearner looks like it's working now. I'm not sure what was happening earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Am I right that this is 2023, we can ask AI to generate fully functional code but we still can't search exact match on GitHub?

Answer (score 254):

You couldn't (*before 2022*). The official GitHub [searching rules](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax):

> Due to the complexity of searching code, there are a few restrictions
> on how searches are performed:
>
> - Only the default branch is considered. In most cases, this will be the *master* branch.
> - Only files smaller than *384 KB* are searchable.
> - Only repositories with fewer than *500,000 files* are searchable.
> - You must always include at least one search term when searching source code. For example, searching for `language:go` is not valid, while `amazing language:go` is.
> - At most, search results can show *two* fragments from the same file, but there may be more results within the file.
> - **You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query**:
>   `` . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] ``
>   *The search will simply ignore these symbols.*

**Update:** GitHub supports literal strings now, but you can also try some more powerful ways below.

---

### Try Sourcegraph

For complex search with regex support try [Sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/search).

[image]

---

### Clone and use `git-grep`:

**git** support searching in sources with [git-grep](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) command. Just clone a repository and use the command in the folder:

```bash
git grep "text-to-search"
```

**Alternatives:**

I recommend you to try [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) tool, it's fast and simple. Works like `git-grep` but looks nicer:

```bash
rg "text-to-search"
```

And you can use the standard `grep` to search any text in files:

```bash
grep -r "text-to-search" /repository
```

Comment: This is terrible. Why don't they fix it? Ideally I should be able to search with a regex. Where do I go to protest this? :)

Comment: I've asked a support and they responsed: "The ability to escape special characters in GitHub search is a frequently-requested feature. While I can't make any promises, I will +1 the idea on our internal Feature Request list.". I think it depends on index size: too many code github contains.

Comment: I believe this is an indexing challenge.
Making the verbatim double-quote search work is prob an order of magnitude harder than present implementation.
Making a regex search work is likely >1 orders of magnitude harder or even possibly [asking for trouble](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

Comment: I'd like to add info missing in Github's docs:
**Another major restriction**: *Phrases with dashes* are ignored entirely, e.g.:
`Bxp-pI-XMk`, `"Bxp-pI-XMk"` & `Bxp-pI-XMk in:file filename:designable.nib` all return 0 results for [TermiT/Flycut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut). Strange I know, as `Bxp-pI-XMk` is plainly seen in [designable.nib](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut/blob/master/English.lproj/MainMenu.nib/designable.nib). No wildcard chars in the phrase, the file's on master + <384k *and* the example uses a "search term" and not filter values in isolation.

Comment: @Xelian you can use the `user:username` syntax for that - the rest needs to be in quotes (`""`)

Comment: what about literal strings that contain dot...like `ldap.mycomp.com`?!?!?!  I don't need a regex, I just want a LITERAL string search

Comment: This is not fix because they use elasticsearch, so they should re-index all the data with a new field to take it in consideration, this means lot of disk.

Comment: So basically no boolean logic operators for search, right?

Comment: I used sourcegraph and it worked a treat. For anyone wondering how to search a *specific repo* on sourcegraph, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223797/search-github-repo-for-term-with-special-characters-using-sourcegraph).

Comment: How do you use literal search strings now that it's 2022 ?

Comment: @DidierA. A year late, but, perhaps [query for an exact match](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#query-for-an-exact-match)?

Comment: @djvg Great, now they put it on a help page. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. GitHub performs a fuzzy search, no matter what.

Answer (score 68):

You can use Google directly.

How about this?

```
"your_string_to_search" site::https://github.com
"your_string_to_search" site::https://gist.github.com
```

Comment: Doesn't that assume that Google has access to your repo?  That shouldn't be the case for private repos.

Comment: @JoelB  I don't know, I think google index only open repos.

Comment: it works inside repos, like: `"alias agi=" site::https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh`

Comment: @juanpastas can you give full example of search string?

Comment: This made more sense back when Google still honoured the quotes to force an exact search.

Comment: could we filter by language using this?

Comment: @FullMetalFist Looks like yes, for example `"your_string_to_search" site:https://github.com filetype:cpp`

Comment: Would be good but doesn't work for two reasons: it'll ignore some special characters like `:` and the result list is not as usable as a site-specific result list could be, for example, things are just dumped, no idea where the hits are in the source tree

Comment: +1 Google is awesome! Was looking for the C# code files that implement all the xUnit Assert functionality and was able to track it down via this search on Google: `inurl:github.com/xunit filetype:cs assert`

Comment: Doesn't correctly match non-alphanumeric characters. Those are instead treated something like the regex `[^_\W]+`. This is a problem when you're searching code expressions.

Answer (score 33):

Today I was trying to look for an exact match of `filter class` in files named `logback.xml` in any repo on Github. And I came up with the following query which did the job.

```
"filter class" in:file filename:logback.xml
```

To enable exact matches with quotes you need to follow your search with the "in:file" modifier.  The matches are not quite exact, the word "class" will have to follow the word "filter", but it seems there can be 0 or more spaces or symbols characters between the two words.

Comment: I see no difference in behavior when searching with or without `in:file`.

Comment: me neither, but the fact that "foo bar" in quotes does search for adjacent words is very useful news to me

Comment: Thanks, it's much better than without it. Notice filename might be a regexp, e.g. `in:file filename:*.js`

Answer (score 25):

1. Open a repository on GitHub, for example [microsoft/fluentui](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui)
2. Press dot "." to open VS Code web interface
3. Go to search in the left panel
4. Enable indexing via the prompt below search bar
5. Huraaay!  exact search works

---

UPDATE: As of November 2022, the solution above only works if you are signed in on GitHub.

You can enable preview of new search experience on this link:
https://github.com/features/code-search-code-view/signup.

Then do exact match just by using quotes: `"system <<-"`

Comment: vscode? could you explain how does it relate to github?

Comment: @Sisir When you open a repository on GitHub.com and press dot `.`, it'll start running VS Code in your browser, with the repository open.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day since cs.github.com makes you sign up on whitelist

Comment: That's a local _repo_ search not a _GitHub search_.
One is a SaaS for `git` and the other is a local `git` repo. -1

Comment: @Ari It is a `repo` search, but not a local repo search. The key is that you don't need to download the repo before searching.

Comment: @Draex_ you might not be downloading repo but "indexing" is still caching on your local machine. Regardless this question was how to search _all of GitHub_ and not one repo!

Comment: I want to search 1000s of repositories at once

Comment: This assumes you have some kind of vscode installed?

Comment: @cgseller No, but when I test it in an incognito window, it no longer works. I guess you have to be signed in on GitHub.

Answer (score 15):

You can: Since Dec. 2021, your search, done from [**`cs.github.com`**](https://cs.github.com/about), can include special characters

> ### [Improving GitHub code search](https://github.blog/2021-12-08-improving-github-code-search/)
>
> (from [Pavel Avgustinov](https://github.com/p0))
>
> Search for an exact string, with support for substring matches and special characters, or use regular expressions (enclosed in `/` separators).

So `"system <<-"` should work, on that new search site.

Comment: It tells me to sign up for the technology preview and I signed up successfully but how many days will take to accept me to start using the feature? The default search in Github is sick and unuseful. Finally can't believe that they did it.

Comment: @Taha I agree, and there seems to be some kind of waiting list there...

Comment: Almost two years later, still in technology preview. :-(

Comment: @EmileCormier True. Latest news: https://github.blog/2021-12-15-a-brief-history-of-code-search-at-github/

Answer (score 11):

Adding to @[mrgloom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179925/mrgloom)'s answer, if you're looking for code in a specific programming language in Github using Google you could do something like this in Google's search bar:

- state the specific string you're looking for using the "intext:" search operator
- add the programming language you're interested in, using the "ext:" operator (i.e. "ext:py", "ext:R", "ext:rb", etc.)
- search in all public repos in Github using the "site:" operator mrgloom mentioned.

Example:

```
intext:"%% 2 == 0" ext:R site:github.com
```

[image: Google Results from the example]

Comment: `intext:".set(" ext:JS site:github.com` didn't work :/

Comment: You're right! I don't understand why... I tried `intext:"set(" inurl:.js site:github.com` and it kinda works, but not really

Comment: So I kept reading and apparently [parenthesis are ignored in google searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/forum/AAAAgtjJeM4I-nOsFWviRs/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fwebsearch%2FI-nOsFWviRs%2FOSXB_PyB0yoJ&msgid=OSXB_PyB0yoJ)
However, I don't understand why the "ext" operator doesn't work.
According to [this](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html#ext) it is an undocumented alias for "filetype", but not sure why "js" would not be considered as one

Answer (score 4):

As of 11/2/2021, this is possible by putting quotation marks around your search string

Without quotes:
[image: Searching chaos monkey on GitHub with unquoted terms]

With quotes:
[image: Searching chaos monkey on GitHub with string]

While it's now possible to search exact strings, the functionality doesn't yet support searching on non-alphanumeric characters. Example:

[image: Searching chaos monkey on GitHub with question mark in quoted string]

Comment: Good explanation. I am amazed (in a bad way) how poor github search is!

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this behavior.  I searched for a string with dots in it like a version number and got hundreds of thousands of results in my repos.

Comment: @cgseller A dot is an example of what this answer calls a special character. I've updated the answer to say 'non-alphanumeric character' to avoid this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

If your package is in debian, you can use their code search, which supports regular expressions: https://codesearch.debian.net/

Answer (score 3):

You can now do regex searches in GitHub using forward slashes rather than quotes, so you can match both exact strings and patterns.  Try the search `/system <<-/` for an exact match, or `/system[\s]*<<-/` for any number of whitespace characters in the middle, for example!

GitHub reference: [Understanding GitHub Code Search syntax > Using regular expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

## The searching query MUST be wrapped between `/` (slashes)

#### Example 1

Search for occurrence of `query = """`, will look like this `/query = """/`

#### Example 2

Search for `query = """` in `test_*.py` files, will look like this `path:**/test_*.py /query = """/`

### Notes

Use [GitHub Search](https://github.com/search) or [Advanced GitHub Search](https://github.com/search/advanced) - be aware that the `advanced search` might still generate some unrecognized qualifiers (e.g. `filename:`)

Answer (score 1):

If your search term is a filename or other substring which contains punctuation characters, a partial workaround to get GitHub's code search to return instances of that substring is to (1) replace the punctuation characters in your search term with spaces, and (2) enclose the search term in quotes.

For example, instead of using the search term:

- `repo:my_repo my_image_asset_1.svg`

Try:

- `repo:my_repo "my image asset 1 svg"`

This might not be a perfect solution in all cases; I imagine it might also match filenames like `my-image-asset-1.svg`. But depending on your use case, it might be "good enough"?

Comment: Thank you! This might be a clumsy workaround, but was the only solution that worked in a corporate github to search over a large number of repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you **quickly want to search inside a specific repo**, try that:

- Press `.` while viewing the repo to open it inside a browser-based VS Code window
- Enter your search term into the menu on the left
- Enable indexing
  [image]

Comment: _"How to search on GitHub"_ not _"How to search on GitHub repo"_ doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not work for me. (hint:  I do not have Microsoft VS Code installed)