# Using Github API code search, find the exact string `throw "`

Tags: github, github-api

I want to find the exact strings, `throw '` and `throw "` in javascript files in a given repo using the Github API.

[It says](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/):

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search
>   query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The
>   search will simply ignore these symbols.

I'm supposing there is no way to find these exact strings using the API?

I have tried various searches with no luck. Trying to escape the `"` with `\` doesn't work either.

https://api.github.com/search/code?q=%22throw+%27%22+in:file+language:js+repo:angular/angular.js

All of the queries I try return, for instance, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/docs/config/tag-defs/tutorial-step.js which just finds the `throw` and disregards the `'`.

An alternative to this strategy is to find where there is `NOT Error` on the line, so that the search is `throw NOT Error` to try to find where someone is throwing a string and not `throw new Error(`. This strategy doesn't work for some reason. For instance,

https://api.github.com/search/code?q=%22throw%20NOT%20Error%22+in:file+language:js+repo:driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest

There are many times that a plain string is thrown in https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js but, the file does contain the string `Error`; so, I guess this is enough to make the result empty. I'm seeing a way to "search" in my client program as a workaround; but, I would rather get the results from the API.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm supposing there is no way to find these exact strings using the API?

Correct, that's not possible currently.

Comment: how about now? :D

Comment: Now you can use quotes to search for exact matches (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638183/3412775). Haven't checked how escaping quotes works within that though.