# GitHub Search: How to search for "C++" or simply "+" in issue content on GitHub?

Tags: github

After trying several methods of searching for the term: "c++" (case insensitive) in a GitHub repository's issues, I've discovered that it only wants to return anything with "c" in it.  I've even found that searching for just "++" yields no results whatsoever.  [GitHub's help](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests) has also not been very helpful in this search.

Is there a way to coax GitHub into escaping the `+`s so as to return such a string with non alpha-character symbols that may normally be considered operators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search on GitHub to get exact string matches, including special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433561/how-to-search-on-github-to-get-exact-string-matches-including-special-character)

Answer (score 1):

Use the search `/c\+\+/`.  The outer forward slashes indicate a regex search, and the backslashes are escaping the plusses since they are special characters in regex.