# How search github issue by EXACT match (like Double Quotes for Google)

Tags: github

*(Note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433561/how-to-search-on-github-to-get-exact-matches-like-what-quotes-do-for-google) is different)*

Is there any way to search through GitHub issues with EXACT match in title, like:

```
is:issue in:title "hello world"
```

By default, (even if quoted) it searches for issues both containing `hello` and `world`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a search engine. For example, in both [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+inurl%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%2Fissues+%22disable+extensions%22)'s and [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Agithub.com+inurl%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%2Fissues+%22disable+extensions%22)'s case:

```
site:github.com inurl:microsoft/vscode/issues "disable extensions"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised too, but this basic functionality has not been implemented. [They say](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/about-searching-on-github):

> Currently our search doesn't support exact matching.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I consider the Github search tool is so weak and I suffer like you to find specific code.

Luckily, The Github team published this [article](https://github.blog/2021-12-08-improving-github-code-search/).

It will be published soon.

---

**Updated the answer**

Sorry because I did misunderstand your question, I think that is not possible until now, so please suggest this feature to the Github team, and maybe in the future they add it.

Comment: The question is about issue search, not code search.

Comment: @mhsmith You are right, How I did not notice that. Thank you for telling me.