# Search github repo for term with special characters using sourcegraph?

Tags: github, github-api, sourcegraph, github-search

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33237640/5783745) to [*How to search on GitHub to get exact string matches, including special characters*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433561/how-to-search-on-github-to-get-exact-string-matches-including-special-character) shows a way to search GitHub for terms that include special characters using a tool called [sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/).

I got that working:

https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+.where%28&patternType=literal

but I'd like to narrow the search to a specific repo (not all of GitHub) - how can I do that?

#### Example

Here's the exact search I tried on GitHub:

https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe/search?q=.where%28

(it searches for `where` instead of `.where(`.

Here's the search on sourcegraph:

https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+.where%28&patternType=literal

It returns results for all of GitHub rather than the specific repo [sharetribe/sharetribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe).

How can I limit this search to one repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit this search by using the `repo` filter:

https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+repo:sharetribe/sharetribe+.where%28&patternType=literal

[image]