# Github code search in repository

Tags: github

**How to search a particular word in code of particular repository on github .
eg: searching function name or class name etc.**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search code inside a Github project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616221/search-code-inside-a-github-project)