# Github search not working as expected for both general and exact phases

Tags: github, github-api

#### Problem: 1

Searching for `"class FirestoreQueryBuilder<Document>"` in this [repository](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/) doesn't show anything.

[image]

But searching for `"class FirestoreQueryBuilder"` returns the page.

[image]

So, why is searching the exact phrase is not working? How do I then search for files?

---

#### Problem 2:

If I search `FirestoreQueryBuilder`, it doesn't even return results for the above class i.e. it doesn't show `class FirestoreQueryBuilder<Document> extends StatefulWidget {`  but other 5 results.

Comment: Apparently, it is still in the works in 2022, see VonC's comment from Dec 18, 2021 at 13:58 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616259/8508004). I just applied for access myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned before in "[Search code inside a Github project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616259/6309)" a work in progress.

Since [May 2023](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-05-08-the-new-code-search-and-code-view-is-now-generally-available/) this work has been completed.

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afirebase%2Fflutterfire+%22class+FirestoreQueryBuilder%3CDocument%3E%22&type=code does work, and shows

```dart
/// {@endtemplate}
/// {@subCategory service:firestore}
/// {@subCategory type:widget}
/// {@subCategory description:A widget that listens to a query.}
/// {@subCategory img:https://place-hold.it/400x150}
class FirestoreQueryBuilder<Document> extends StatefulWidget {
...
}
```