# Java wait0() native implementation source

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I was looking into Object.wait for Java and found out that it internally calls a wait0() method. You can find it's declaration in [openJdk here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L387):

```java
public final void wait(long timeoutMillis) throws InterruptedException {
    long comp = Blocker.begin();
    try {
        wait0(timeoutMillis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        if (thread.isVirtual())
            thread.getAndClearInterrupt();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        Blocker.end(comp);
    }
}

// final modifier so method not in vtable
private final native void wait0(long timeoutMillis) throws InterruptedException;
```

Can anyone point out to me where is the implementation for this native wait0() method?

Comment: Clone the code and search for it. That's what everyone else does.

Comment: That won't help them find a `native` implementation.

Comment: probably `JVM_MonitorWait` in `jvm.cpp`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/24c3d86f32a2e2d9cb24cd8827ef1f20bb53fead/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#L631

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It will if you understand JNI and know how it mangles the name.

Comment: Which, of course, they don't, which is why the question got posted ;) And of course no one needs to clone a repo to see a file, it has its own URL in the same repo as they linked to, just in a different directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Where is it?

The implementation can be found in [`objectMonitor.cpp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L1440).

#### The path to `wait0`

While the Java sources are stored in a directory called `classes`, native code is stored in the [native](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.base/share/native) directory.
Specifically, you want the [native/libjava](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava) directory containing native code for some core Java classes.

In there, you can find a file called [`Object.c`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Object.c) containing some native code for the `Object` class. However, that class doesn't seem to contain much useful stuff except including `jvm.h`.

Thisheader file contains a [`JVM_MonitorWait`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/include/jvm.h#L70) function declaration and its implementation can be [found in `jvm.cpp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#L631).

Most importantly, that function calls `ObjectSynchronizer::wait` which is in turn [declared in a file called `synchronizer.hpp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/24c3d86f32a2e2d9cb24cd8827ef1f20bb53fead/src/hotspot/share/runtime/synchronizer.hpp#L116).
In the same directory, you can find a file called synchronizer.cpp containing [the implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#L713) which calls `ObjectMonitor::wait`.

Finally, you can find the code of `ObjectMonitor::wait` [in `objectMonitor.cpp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L1440).

#### How to navigate

##### IDE

The best way to find what you are looking for in a codebase like this is to clone the project and set it up in an IDE that can search the methods for you. However, setting up a project like the JDK in an IDE and building it can be tedious and might take a while.

##### with a browser

You can also navigate through the repository in your browser by looking for files with names similar to what you are looking for (e.g. using GitHub's `Go To File` feature).

However, in some cases, you might want to use some sort of full text search. In cases like that, you could try GitHub Codespaces or the GitHub Code search [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616259/10871900). For doing this, you navigate to https://github.com/search, enter `repo:` followed by the repository name (including user/org, in this case `repo:openjdk/jdk`) as well as the text you want to search. Then, you can switch to the code search for the given term.