# How does grep run so fast?

Tags: unix, grep

I am really amazed by the functionality of GREP in shell, earlier I used to use substring method in java but now I use GREP for it and it executes in a matter of seconds, it is blazingly faster than java code that I used to write.(according to my experience I might be wrong though)

That being said I have not been able to figure out how it is happening? there is also not much available on the web.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It is open source so you can have a look for yourself. http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/devel.html

Comment: Ridiculous Fish has a great writeup answering exactly your question: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/old-age-and-treachery.html

Comment: @WilliamPursell When the execution time goes in the seconds, the JIT has probably warmed up and the mind-numbing difference is due to (1) grep being incredibly smart about what it does and (2) the Java code making a pretty bad algorithm choice for the specific problem grep focuses on.

Comment: How much time does your Java implementation spend starting up the JVM, and how much time does it spend actually executing your code? Or it might be a matter of the algorithm you used in your Java code; an O(N^2) algorithm is likely to be slow in any language.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Assuming your question regards `GNU grep` specifically. Here's a note from the author, Mike Haertel:

> GNU grep is fast because it AVOIDS LOOKING AT EVERY INPUT BYTE.
>
> GNU grep is fast because it EXECUTES VERY FEW INSTRUCTIONS FOR EACH
>   BYTE that it 
>   *does* look at.
>
> GNU grep uses the well-known Boyer-Moore algorithm, which looks first
>   for the final letter of the target string, and uses a lookup table to
>   tell it how far ahead it can skip in the input whenever it finds a
>   non-matching character.
>
> GNU grep also unrolls the inner loop of Boyer-Moore, and sets up the
>   Boyer-Moore delta table entries in such a way that it doesn't need to
>   do the loop exit test at every unrolled step.  The result of this is
>   that, in the limit, GNU grep averages fewer than 3 x86 instructions
>   executed for each input byte it actually looks at (and it skips many
>   bytes entirely).
>
> GNU grep uses raw Unix input system calls and avoids copying data
>   after reading it. Moreover, GNU grep AVOIDS BREAKING THE INPUT INTO
>   LINES.  Looking for  newlines would slow grep down by a factor of
>   several times, because to find the newlines it would have to look at
>   every byte!
>
> So instead of using line-oriented input, GNU grep reads raw data into
>   a large buffer, searches the buffer using Boyer-Moore, and only when
>   it finds a match does it go and look for the bounding newlines
>   (Certain command line options like 
>   -n disable this optimization.)

This answer is a subset of the information taken from [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html).

Answer (score 56):

To add to Steve's excellent answer.

It may not be widely known but grep is almost always ***faster*** when grepping for a ***longer*** pattern-string than a short one, because in a longer pattern, *Boyer-Moore* can skip forward in longer strides to achieve even better ***sublinear*** speeds:

Example:

```
# after running these twice to ensure apples-to-apples comparison
# (everything is in the buffer cache) 

$ time grep -c 'tg=f_c' 20140910.log
28
0.168u 0.068s 0:00.26

$ time grep -c ' /cc/merchant.json tg=f_c' 20140910.log
28
0.100u 0.056s 0:00.17
```

The longer form is 35% faster!

How come? *Boyer-Moore* consructs a skip-forward table from the pattern-string, and whenever there's a mismatch, it picks the longest skip possible (from last char to first) before comparing a single char in the input to the char in the skip table.

Here's [a video explaining Boyer Moore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xyhb72LCX4)  (Credit to kommradHomer)

Another common misconception (for GNU grep) is that `fgrep` is faster than `grep`. `f` in `fgrep` doesn't stand for 'fast', it stands for 'fixed' (see the man page), and since both are the same program, and both use *Boyer-Moore*, there's no difference in speed between them when searching for fixed-strings without regexp special chars.  The only reason I use `fgrep` is when there's a regexp special char (like `.`, `[]`, or `*`) I don't want it to be interpreted as such.  And even then the more portable/standard form of `grep -F` is preferred over `fgrep`.

Comment: It's intuitive that longer patterns are faster. If the pattern was one byte then grep would have to check every byte. If the pattern is 4-bytes then it could makes 4-byte skips. If the pattern was as long as text then grep would only do one step.

Comment: Yes, it is intuitive -- if you understand how Boyer-Moore works.

Comment: Even otherwise it's intuitive. It would be easier to find a long needle in a haystack than a shorter one

Comment: Invalid analogy. Grep needs to compare _all_ the characters of a string, to verify a full match, unlike the 'long needle' case where it is enough to find any tiny piece of metal in the haystack. The _skips_  and the starting from the _end_, are the critical and non-intuitive points.

Comment: The counter example to "being faster when longer" is cases where you have to do a lot of tests before you fail, and you can't move ahead anyway. Say the file `xs.txt` contains 100000000 'x's, and you do `grep yx xs.txt`, then it actually fails to find a match sooner than if you do `grep yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xs.txt`. The Boyer-Moore-Horspool improvement to Boyer-Moore improves on the skip-ahead in that case, but it's probably not going to be only three machine instructions in the general case.

Comment: the "good" video you have linked is unwatchable for anyone with functional ears . here is a better one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xyhb72LCX4

Comment: Thanks @kommradHomer - replaced video link and dropped the 'good' qualifier.

Comment: @arielf kudos for taking the time to do so on an old answer :)

Comment: At my side, `grep -F string` is a bit faster than `grep string`, which is faster than `grep [s]tring` which still is faster than `fgrep string`.  The latter looks puzzling, until you realize, that `/bin/fgrep` is a shell script just running `exec grep -F "$@"`, thus does one more `exec()` (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: @Tino thanks. Yes, it seems that the days of (GNU) `grep/fgrep/egrep` being all hardlinks to the same executable are gone. They (and other extensions like the `z*grep` `bz*grep` utils which decompress on the fly), are now small shell-wrappers around `grep`. Some interesting historical comments on the switch between a single executable & shell wrappers can be found in this commit:
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=b639643840ef506594b6c46e5b24d9980a33e78e