# Fast way to find string in file in unix

Tags: unix

I want to find string pattern in file in unix. I use below command:

```
$grep 2005057488 filename
```

But file contains millions of lines and i have many such files. What is fastest way to get pattern other than grep.

Answer (score 19):

`grep` is generally as fast as it gets. It's designed to one thing and one thing only - and it does what it does very well. You can read why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629749/how-does-grep-run-so-fast).

However, to speed things up there are a couple of things you could try. Firstly, it looks like the pattern you're looking for is a fixed string. Fortunately, `grep` has a 'fixed-strings' option:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
       Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. (-F is specified by POSIX.)
```

Secondly, because `grep` is generally pretty slow on `UTF-8`, you could try disabling national language support (NLS) by setting the environment `LANG=C`. Therefore, you could try this concoction:

```
LANG=C grep -F "2005057488" file
```

Thirdly, it wasn't clear in your question, but if your only trying to find if something exists once in your file, you could also try adding a maximum number of times to find the pattern. Therefore, when `-m 1`, `grep` will quit immediately after the first occurrence is found. Your command could now look like this:

```
LANG=C grep -m 1 -F "2005057488" file
```

Finally, if you have a multicore CPU, you could give [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) a go. It even comes with an [explanation of how to use it with grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__parallel_grep). To run 1.5 jobs per core and give 1000 arguments to `grep`:

```
find . -type f | parallel -k -j150% -n 1000 -m grep -H -n STRING {}
```

To `grep` a big file in parallel use `--pipe`:

```
< bigfile parallel --pipe grep STRING
```

Depending on your disks and CPUs it may be faster to read larger blocks:

```
< bigfile parallel --pipe --block 10M grep STRING
```

Comment: Is there a way to know the status of grep. I am asking this becuase, when searching for file with order of 50GB, I often like to know the status of cursor its searching for

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan: I'm not sure what you mean by 'status of cursor'. If you mean 'progress', then I would usually use `pv` (pipe viewer).

Answer (score 2):

grep works faster than sed.

```
$grep 2005057488 filename
$sed -n '/2005057488/p' filename
```

Still Both works to get that particular string in a file

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/2005057488/p' filename
```

Not sure if this is faster than grep though.

Comment: It's unlikely. `grep` is designed to do just one thing (see my answer)

Comment: @steve, should I delete my answer then? New to SO. Please help.