# Faster way to grep from big file

Tags: bash, unix

I have .bz2 file and i need to grep I keyword and get count .
I am using below command and file is very big more then 5 hundred million rows. Any way i can make below command faster.

```
bzgrep -c "I$" filename.bz2
```

Comment: Post the entire command you are using, including the pipe.

Comment: I have edited my question with full command.

Comment: [Relevant?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13913220/1735215)

Comment: First of all my file is compressed file so fgrep will not work.Secondly i tried LC_ALL=C but no performance improvement.

Comment: @MrAdfire Okay, was worth a try. What about the other answers to this question. The second most voted one suggests to use GNU parallel to pipe a large file (in this case an sql file) into grep. I do not know, however, if it would work with bzgrep.

Comment: @orange Tried it doesn't work .