# Best way for search in big tree

Tags: tree, bigdata

I have big list of domains names, like:

```
site.com
ns1.site.com
ns2.site.com
test.main.site.com
google.com
mail.google.com
etc.
```

The count of row around 10^9.
I search best way to store this and find all subdomains by main domain.

For example, search query is:

```
site.com
```

Result will be:

```
ns1.site.com
ns2.site.com
test.main.site.com
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What language/tool are you using? If you have `grep` installed you can do `grep "site.com" inputfile`.

Comment: I am searching for best t language/tool for this task. Grep is too slow for me. I have ~ 10^9 lines.

Comment: You can speed up grep with the techniques mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913014/grepping-a-huge-file-80gb-any-way-to-speed-it-up

Answer (score 0):

You can use some real-time full-text search tool in which you store each domain name separately. Then you can run LIKE query with the given input, and it will return all domain names that contain your input string in them.

Some popular real-time full-text search engines are [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Both should satisfy your conditions.