# How to search a word from multiple documents in java?

Tags: java

My actual requirement is to list all the files in the given directory which contains the search phrase `textToMatch` in minimum amount of time about `4-5` seconds, where number of files could be upto `100000` or more.

I don't want code, just I want a best algorithm for this.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm and https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

Comment: Use `grep -l textToMatch *.txt`.

Comment: Don't think you can achieve this without building up a search index.

Comment: You *can* do this by using the proper tool.

Comment: For an idea how a fast algorithm could be implemented, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12630617/6999902

Answer (score 1):

Since you will have to open every file, you can also use a tool build for this specific task. Use [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

We have 100000 files to look at.

```
% ls -l *.txt | wc -l          
100000
```

They contain `Vestibulum`.

```
% grep Vestibulum 1.txt        
Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt.
euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus
```

Count the files containing `Vestibulum`, time this.

```
% time grep -l Vestibulum *.txt | wc -l
100000
grep --color=auto -l Vestibulum *.txt  0,28s user 0,25s system 99% cpu 0,537 total
wc -l  0,00s user 0,01s system 1% cpu 0,537 total
```

As you see, this takes only have a second on my machine.

Comment: What is `grep` and how i can do this using `grep` in java can u give me full program ?

Comment: How I can do this in java. I am using Windows system.

Comment: Since the question is tagged as a java question, Mickey Patel is probably just asking for an algorithm description and not for specific operating systems commands and tools.

Comment: Why reimplement `grep` in Java?

Comment: Why the java tag then? Let him explain.

Comment: ya i want to do this using java application. I don't want to use any specific tools for this.

Comment: Well, the you have some options: 1) find a library that implements a *fast* algorithm as `grep` does (I know no such library), 2) implement such an algorithm yourself (good luck).

Answer (score 0):

Your program must deal with 2 issues:

1. Locating each and every file in each and every subdirectory and
2. Searching for the phrase you need inside every file.

For 1: You can search the given directory for files either iteratively or recursively or let Java 7 or 8 do the work for you by using either a [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) or [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/index.html).

For 2: You could use a [Java Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or implement your self the very fast algorithm for searching inside files, called the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm.