# Does `std::wregex` support utf-16/unicode or only UCS-2?

Tags: c++, regex, unicode, encoding, widechar

With [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) the [regex library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) was introduced into the standard library.

On the Windows/MSVC platform `wchar_t` has size of 2 (16 bit) and `wchar_t*` is normally [utf-16](/questions/tagged/utf-16) when interfacing with the system/platform (eg. `CreateFileW`).

However it seems that `std::regex` isn't [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) or does not support it, so I'm wondering whether `std::wregex` supports [utf-16](/questions/tagged/utf-16) or just [ucs2](/questions/tagged/ucs2) ?

I do not find any mention of this (Unicode or the like) in the documentation. In other languages *normalization* takes place.

The question is:

**Is `std::wregex` representing [ucs2](/questions/tagged/ucs2) when `wchar_t` has size of 2 ?**

Comment: AFAIK no `std::regex` implementation *properly* supports Unicode. Also, they are *all* extremely slow. Don’t use them, use something like re2 instead. See https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/e16s1m/what_is_wrong_with_stdregex/ and https://reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/aetf17/stdregex_replacestdchronohigh_resolution_clocknow/edsfwe1/

Comment: @KonradRudolph speed may be of a lesser concern sometimes or for some parts of code - but its a good comment though.

Comment: It’s a concern when it’s eight hundred times (!!!) slower than other implementations.

Comment: Windows uses UTF16 and Visual C++ itself supports standard UTF16 strings, ie `u16string`. C++ itself doesn't have special handling for UTF8 until C++20 and UTF8 strings are treated as char arrays - regex would work if you first encoded your non-English strings as UTF8.

Comment: Now [std::wregex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/wregex/) is a `typedef basic_regex<wchar_t> wregex;` so it works with `wchar_t`, ie UCS-2. That shouldn't be a concern unless you want to handle Chinese or emojis. You can probably create a `basic_regex<char16_t>` to handle UTF16 strings. For whatever reason though, that's left as an exercise to the reader

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do want that, but thats another concern - why not post as an answer though ?

Comment: `I do not find any mention of this (unicode or the like) in the documentation.` depends on the documentation you're looking at. C++20 will bring basic UTF8 support anc `char8_t` with conversions going out to C++23. `char8_t` alone will be a headache for any code that assumed UTF8==char. [String and Character Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019) in the Visual C++ docs explains how Unicode is handled today, and how the compiler handles conversions between `wchar_t` and `char16_t`

Comment: @darune nope. No way. Every time I try to post an answer about C++ and Unicode i get roasted because I don't know all the intricacies of the committee process. I've worked far too long with native Unicode languages like C#, Java and Javascript. Besides, the actual answer to your question is `Not before 2023 at least`.

Comment: @darune and as I said, the committee left `basic_regex<char16_t>` out of the library itself. They must have had a reason, eg too tricky conversions? Edge cases? They plan to replace `std::regex` altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ standard doesn't enforce any encoding on [`std::string` and `std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). They're simply a series of `CharT`. Only `std::u8string`, `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` have defined encoding

- [What encoding does std::string.c_str() use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1010783/995714)
- [Does std::string in c++ has encoding format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58606936/995714)

Similarly [`std::regex` and `std::wregex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) also wrap around `std::basic_string` and `CharT`. [Their constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex) accept `std::basic_string` and the encoding being used for `std::basic_string` will also be used for `std::basic_regex`. So what you said *"std::regex isn't utf-8 or does not support it"* is wrong. If the current locale is UTF-8 then `std::regex` and `std::string` will be UTF-8 (yes, modern Windows does support [UTF-8 locale](https://superuser.com/q/1033088/241386))

On Windows `std::wstring` uses UTF-16 so `std::wregex` also uses UTF-16. UCS-2 is deprecated and no one uses it anymore. You don't even need to differentiate between then since UCS-2 is just a subset of UTF-16 unless you use some very old tool that cuts in the middle of a surrogate pair. String searches in UTF-16 works exactly the same as in UCS-2 because [UTF-16 is self-synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52226539/995714) and a proper needle string can never match from the middle of a haystack. Same to UTF-8. If the tool doesn't understand UTF-16 then it's highly likely that it doesn't know that UTF-8 is variable length either, and will truncate the UTF-8 in the middle

> Self-synchronization: The leading bytes and the continuation bytes do not share values (continuation bytes start with 10 while single bytes start with 0 and longer lead bytes start with 11). **This means a search will not accidentally find the sequence for one character starting in the middle of another character.** It also means the start of a character can be found from a random position by backing up at most 3 bytes to find the leading byte. An incorrect character will not be decoded if a stream starts mid-sequence, and a shorter sequence will never appear inside a longer one.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

The only things you need to care about are: avoid truncating in the middle of a character, and normalize the string before matching if necessary. The former issue can be avoided in UCS-2-only regex engines if you never use characters outside the BMP in a character class like commented. Replace them with a group instead

> In other languages normalization takes place.

This is wrong. Some languages may do normalization before matching a regex, but that definitely doesn't apply to all "other languages"

If you want a little bit more assurance then use `std::basic_regex<char8_t>` and `std::basic_regex<char16_t>` for UTF-8 and UTF-16 respectively. You'll still need a UTF-16-aware library though, otherwise that'll still only work for regex strings that only contain words

The better solution may be changing to another library like [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). You can check [Comparison of regular expression engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) for some suggestions. It even has a column indicating [native UTF-16 support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#API_features) for each library

Related:

- [Do C++11 regular expressions work with UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11254232/995714)
- [How well is Unicode supported in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17103925/995714)
- [How do I properly use std::string on UTF-8 in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50403342/995714)
- [How to use Unicode range in C++ regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37989081/995714)

See also

- [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/)
- [Unicode Support in the Standard Library](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3572.html)

Comment: After some more testing, it seems my main problem is matching a group, eg. an emoji with utf-16. It doesn't match no matter if i invert the group.

Comment: @darune you mean character class, like `[]`? because a group like `()` should be matched without any problem. A class is more tricky because the engine must be UTF-16 aware

Comment: a workaround for an old UCS-2 only regex engine is `(||)`

Comment: It seems I meant character class, not group - but really good point