# Git Transfer Protocol Specifications

Tags: git

I'm playing around with [git's transfer protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols), and I was just wondering if there is some detailed specification for them before I attempt to read the source?

Comment: Note: 5 years later, I have updated [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799460/6309) to reference the **Git transfer protocol v2** which comes with Git 2.18 in Q2 2018.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update May 2018: Starting Q2 2018 and Git 2.18, you will have the **Git transfer protocol v2**: See "[How does Git's transfer protocol work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273976/6309)".

---

Original answer 2013:

First, check the git documentation in the git repo itself (with a [good grep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14871646/6309), available [even on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)):

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
cd git/Documentation
grep -nRHI "receive-pack" *
```

That will give you pointers to:

- [http-protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt)
  But also:
- [pack-heuristics](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt)
- [pack-protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt)
- [protocol capabilities](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/protocol-capabilities.txt)
- [`send-pack` pipeline](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/send-pack-pipeline.txt)

Then you can complete that set of documentation with ones related to the backend commands:

- [`git-http-backend`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-http-backend.txt)
- [`git-receive-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-receive-pack.txt)
- [`git-remote-ext`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-remote-ext.txt)
- [`git-send-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-send-pack.txt)
- [`gitremote-helpers`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitremote-helpers.txt)

---

One way at looking at the source is by looking at the recent evolutions around transfer and transport in the git repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
cd git
git log -Stransfer
```

Have a look at:

- [commit 4bc444](http://github.com/git/git/commit/4bc444eb64173f770c1d1dba2ed3db393c2a9b18) (Support FTP-over-SSL/TLS for regular FTP)
- [commit daebaa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/daebaa78137d59693a808c1f0bdec0ecb40fc12e) (upload/receive-pack: allow hiding ref hierarchies )
- [commit 745f7a](http://github.com/git/git/commit/745f7a8cacae55df3e00507344d8db2a31eb57e8) (fetch-pack: move core code to libgit.a)
- [commit fe0435](http://github.com/git/git/commit/fe0435011cfc5f0c15bbd4548ce0015f5b8ad430) (Add persistent-https to contrib)
- ...

---

Another way is to have a look at other implementation of git:

- Java: **[jgit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit)**, and its [`Transport.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/Transport.java) source (tested in [`TransportTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/TransportTest.java), which declines into:

  - [TCpTransport](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/TcpTransport.java)
  - [TransportHttp](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/TransportHttp.java)
  - [TransportSftp](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/TransportSftp.java)
  - [TransportLocal](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/TransportLocal.java.java)
  - [TransportBundle](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/TransportBundle.java)

- C, with [**libgit2**](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2), and its [`src/transports`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/development/src/transports) sources.
- ... and so on

Comment: Von, thanks for the great answer. I wasn't looking in the right places.

Comment: See also [Packfile transfer protocols](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-protocol.html), [Git Protocol Capabilities](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/protocol-capabilities.html), [Smart HTTP Transport](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) for informative, although maybe old, information.

Comment: Note: pack-protocol finally (Git 2.5, July 2015) get to mention smart http: https://github.com/git/git/commit/486b51bc81e486c654ac35554b284816f4a6ae5c

Answer (score 3):

there is also a partially completed [documentation](https://gist.github.com/schacon/6092633) hosted on Github Gist.

[This](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/c1718fa490be0a5bbf4a1bf48dd9f52a55c67e6c/modules/exploits/multi/http/git_client_command_exec.rb) metasploit module also poses as a malicious dumb git server, serving bad git trees. You can see how the git trees are constructed.