# Git v1.8 backwards compatibility with Git v1.7

Tags: git, backwards-compatibility

If I upgrade from git 1.7 to git 1.8 on my server, do I have to update my repository too?  Will a git 1.7 client work with a git 1.8 server and vice versa?  Is there anything to be concerned about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I have to update my repository too?

No, the internal format of a repo remains compatible.

> Will a git 1.7 client work with a git 1.8 server and vice versa?

Yes, there is little change in the [transport protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799460/6309) (mainly in [http protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt)).

The [protocol capabilities](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/protocol-capabilities.txt) don't mention any backward compatibility issue.