# Search files containing string recursively in solaris

Tags: file, search, recursion, solaris

Looking for solaris command for getting list of all files containing search pattern (recursively). I know how to do it for linux but same command is not working in solaris:

```
bash-3.2# uname -a
SunOS D1NCIC-CL01 5.10 Generic_148888-03 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-15000

bash-3.2# find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "contentInFile"
xargs: illegal option -- 0
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]
find: bad option -print0
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I grep recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)

Comment: `bash-3.2# grep -r "include"`
`grep: illegal option -- r`
`Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .`

i am looking for alternate command for solaris

Answer (score 7):

As is so often the case when combined with `find`, `xargs` is useless here. You can run this portable command on both Solaris and Linux to get what you want:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "contentInFile" {} +
```

Comment: subquestion: what is the + for?

Comment: @Beginner The `+` is there to perform the same argument aggregation as `xargs` does, but a simpler way, i.e. the `grep` command won't be called as much times as there are executable files but typically once. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find

Answer (score 1):

If your filenames don't contain any whitespace, simply use `-print` and omit the `-0` from `xargs`.

If they do, upgrade to Solaris 11, and use `/usr/gnu/bin/find` and `/usr/gnu/bin/xargs` ([GNU Tools out of the box in Solaris 11](http://www.sunsolarisadmin.com/solaris-11/gnu-tools-out-of-the-box-in-solaris-11/)).

Alternatively, if you're stuck on Solaris 10, install the GNU Find Utilities ([How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)), or one of the alternative search tools suggested in [How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively) (`Ag`, `ack`).

Comment: Search location can contain spaces in files/directory names.

`bash-3.2# find . -type f -print | xargs grep -l "contentInFile"`
`grep: can't open ./l2dashboard`
`grep: can't open rules/syslog_cl1.rules`