# Grep Recursively from root directory

Tags: windows, grep

[How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)

I've looked at the above and for me at least it won't recurse if I start from a root directory. This is a on a Windows 7.1 using CMD.EXE

On a network share I'm trying to extract all lines with the word PAY from series of files called TRADING.EOD in a series of folders DATA151101, DATA151102, DATA151103, etc which are created in the root folder which has been mapped to S:

```
grep -r --include="TRADING.EOD" "PAY" .
```

gives me

```
grep: .: Invalid argument
```

alternatively from my  local hard drive I get

```
grep: unable to record current working directory: Bad file descriptor (local hard drive
```

Ideas on how I might get this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the command:

```
findstr /S "PAY" TRADING.EOD
```

it will search in your current directory (+subfolders)

Output will be:

```
DATA151101\TRADING.EOD:PAY <Text after "PAY" in file>
DATA151102\TRADING.EOD:PAY <Text after "PAY" in file>
```

EDIT:
if you want to search in mapped Drive "S:" use command:

```
cd /d S:
```

first.