# Where is this ini setting being made?

Tags: php

I am trying to work out where on earth this PHP ini setting is being made (below script is the only output on the script).

---

**ini_get()**

```
echo ini_get('sendmail_path');
//  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

---

**phpinfo()**

```
Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

---

**/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini**

```
sendmail_path = "sudo /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -X /var/log/mail.log"
```

---

**.htaccess**

```
php_value sendmail_path 'sendmail -t -i -X /var/log/mail.log'
```

---

So how on earth is this setting being set?? Is there a way to see where the setting is coming from?

Comment: Have you tried a recursive search for `sendmail_path` on your web server.

Comment: change the setting, test and see which...

Comment: how would I do the recursive search?

Comment: I think this could work but I'm no Linux expert: [**`find / "*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "send_mail"`**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-recursively-search-all-files-for-words/)

Comment: Or check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1987926/2191572

Comment: If you have full control of the web server then also check for `php_value sendmail_path` within a vhost entry

Comment: This is all well and good but phpinfo reports where the ini file is! So I am confused

Comment: `phpinfo()` does you ZERO good if your PHP code has `ini_set('sendmail_path', '/some/crazy/path');` buried in the code. This is why I suggested the recursive search because it will reveal any PHP files messing with the `sendmail_path`. Same thing goes for the potential vhost entry.

Comment: What I'm saying is my code file is simply `<?php echo ini_get('sendmail_path'); ?>`

Comment: Whatever, don't perform a recursive search; good luck to you.

Comment: _“This is all well and good but phpinfo reports where the ini file is! ”_ – so what? php.ini is only one of multiple ways to set/change configuration values. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this wasn't working was because of an error in my php.ini file and it reverted back to the default option. I found this in the apache error log and from there was able to fix it.