# Extract occurrences of pattern from multiple files

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to find all occurrences of three characters between a pair of spaces in all files in my current directory.

So far I have

```
sed 's/.../(&)/g'
```

I know it's not right; I think I'm stuck on something. How can I do that?

Comment: see also [Find text within a given directory, recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/grep/2198/getting-started-with-grep/10692/find-text-within-a-given-directory-recursively#t=201611080646111179158)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -r -l ' [a-zA-Z]{3} ' .
```

**Explanation:**

```
-r grep recursively from the current folder (.)
-l only display file names, rather than all matching lines
```

The regex I used is `[a-zA-Z]{3}`, which matches three characters in between a pair of spaces, anywhere within a given file.

Comment: `^.*` and `.*` are not needed... need to use `-E` option or `\{3\}`.. also, better to use single quotes instead of double if substitution is not needed... see [How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively) for grep versions without `-r` option...

Comment: @Sundeep I updated my answer, thanks for the feedback.