# List all files within files recursively in Unix?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I'm trying to to `grep` through all the files within a certain directory. Is there a way to recursively list all directories & the files/directories within them via something like `ls`?

Comment: Do you want to match filenames or file contents?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs; you want `find` rather than `ls` if `grep -r` doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Looking to match both file names & file contents @thatotherguy

Comment: @tripleee `grep -r` should solve it. Thanks

Comment: FYI, `grep -r` will not match by filename, only file contents. To match by filename, you can use `find mydir -name '*foo*'` or more casually `find mydir | grep foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the -r option for grep. Here is a reference: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-grep-command-to-search-files-in-linux/#recursive-search.

The search matches list out the path to the files that match your pattern as well. Should be easy to extract that out using something like `cut`

Comment: Awesome. This answers the question better than the suggested duplicate post found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively