# why is grep failing to find a pattern in a file

Tags: grep

I am trying

```
grep -rn '*.cpp' -e 'aPattern'
```

to find the pattern `aPattern` recursively in a directory withing cpp files 
but I got

```
*.cpp no such file or directory
```

why is this failing? there are cpp files in the subdirectories

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution

```
grep -rn --include '*.hpp' -e 'aPattern'
```

the key is to put `--include`

even better

```
grep --color -rn --include '*.hpp' -e 'aPattern'
```