# Linux command line: Find all files with a certain extension in a directory tree containing specific text

Tags: linux, grep

I would like to recursively traverse a directory tree and extract all files which contain a certain text in a remote Linux machine. I found a helpful command in [this website](https://winaero.com/find-files-containing-text-linux/):

```
grep -iRl "your-text-to-find" ./
```

Now however, I would like to modify this slightly by searching only in python (.py) files. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
grep -iRl "your-text-to-find" ./*.py
```

How can I modify the command such that it recursively finds all .py files containing `"your-text-to-find`?

Comment: `find ./ -type f -iname '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 grep "your-text-to-find"`? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively

Comment: That seems a lot more complicated than the commands in my original question... does it really have to be that complex?

Comment: Again,there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684886/3832970) in that thread, `grep -riL --include "*.py" "your-text-to-find" .`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not really, since I am looking for only .py files. That answer basically does the same thing as the first command example in my question...

Comment: Look again at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684886/3832970, just replace `txt` with `py`

Comment: If you want to recursively want to check the directory tree, we will need to use find,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through a few extra posts including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833128/what-does-xargs-grep-do), I found a command which works.

I am not exactly sure what `xargs` does but [the post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833128/what-does-xargs-grep-do) I mentioned explains a bit more:

```
 find ./ -name *.py | xargs grep "text-to-find"
```