# Is there a way to make "grepping" for space less verbose?

Tags: grep, space, windows-7-x64

I often use grep to do searches like

```
    grep -nr "matchFound[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*true" .
```

to look for something like

```
    matchFound = true
    matchFound   =   true
```

But just for the sake of space, the syntax is so verbose. Is it possible to make it less verbose?

Please note: I am using grep on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -nr "matchFound\s*=\s*true"
```

Comment: Usually, `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n]` in regular expressions, to be more precise. Some other flavors are possible, though, but they should be exotic.

Comment: Wild guess: try double-escaping: `\\s`. On a similar note, this worked for me in cygwin: `$ echo "matchFound   = true" | grep -nr "matchFound\s*=\s*true"` gave `1:matchFound   = true`.

Comment: I'll try it on Cygwin and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, this works on Cygwin. I am not sure how I can get this to work without Cygwin, but thanks for the answer .

Comment: So, what kind of the `grep` utility are you using?

Comment: I had a setup file and some DLLs. I don't remember where I got it from. But with that I can use grep on Windows without having anything like Cygwin. But I suppose in such kinds of situations it fails.

Comment: OK, have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows) - it has a fair amount of discussion about good Windows grep tools.

Comment: Thanks to you, now I am using mintty on Cygwin!! It's so much better than the usual Windows Command Prompt.