# Removing specific tags in a KML file

Tags: list, tags, kml

I have a KML file which is a list of places around the world with coordinates and some other attributes. It looks like this for one place:

```
<Placemark>
<name>Albania - Durrës</name>
<open>0</open>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<description>(Spot ID: 275801) show <![CDATA[<a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?go=1&vs=1&sc=275801">forecast</a>]]></description>
<styleUrl>#wgStyle001</styleUrl><Point>
<coordinates>19.489747,41.277806,0</coordinates>
</Point>
<LookAt><range>200000</range><longitude>19.489747</longitude><latitude>41.277806</latitude></LookAt>
</Placemark>
```

I would like to remove everything except the name of the place. So in this case that would mean I would like to remove everything except

```
<name>Albania - Durrës</name>
```

The problem is, this KML file includes more than 1000 of these places. Doing this manually obviously isn't an option, so then how can I remove all tags except for the name tags for all of the items in the list? Can I use some kind of program for that?

Comment: Don't you want to keep the coordinates also? Or you don't want it to be a KML file when you are done?

Comment: No I want it to be an XML file with a list of the city names :) .

Comment: To be a valid XML document, it will need a root tag as well as the `<name>` tags.

Comment: What do you mean by a root tag? I thought I should replace <name> with <item> and then define it as a string-array.

Comment: It would be helpful for those of us reviewing your question if you would elaborate by including an abbreviated example of the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use a specialized command line tool that understands XML documents.

One such tool is [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php), which is available [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php) for Linux, Windows and Solaris.

To address your particular problem, I used the xmlstarlet executable `xml.exe` like this (on Windows):

```
xml.exe sel -N ns=http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 -t -v /ns:kml/ns:Document/ns:Placemark/ns:name places.kml
```

This produces this output:

```
Albania - Durrës
Second Name
Third Name
...
Final Name
```

If you can guarantee that `<name>` occurs only as a child of `<Placemark>`, then this abbreviated version will produce the same result:

```
xml.exe sel -N ns=http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 -t -v //ns:name places.kml
```

*(This is because this shorter version finds all* `<name>` *elements no matter where they occur in the document.)*

If you really want an XML document, you'll need to do a little post-processing. Here's an example of a complete XML document:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<items>
  <item>Albania - Durrës</item>
  <item>Second Name</item>
  <item>Third Name</item>
  <!-- ... -->
  <item>Final Name</item>
</items>
```

This first line is the XML declaration. It declares the Unicode encoding `utf-8`. You'll need to include this line so that XML processors recognize that your document includes Unicode characters. (As in **Durrës**.)

**More:** Here's an enhanced 'xmlstarlet' command that will produce the XML document above:

```
xml.exe sel -N ns=http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 -T -t -o "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" -n -t -v "'<items>'" -n -t -m //ns:Placemark -v "concat('<item>',ns:name,'</item>')" -n -t -o "</items>" -n places.kml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux or similar:

```
grep "<name>" your_file.kml > file_with_only_name_tags
```

On windows, see [What are good grep tools for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows)

Comment: Yes, as @JonoB suggests, a command line tool can do most of what you are after. All Windows machines include the `findstr` program. See @JonoB's link for more or bring up a command prompt and enter `findstr /?`. But keep in mind this approach will only work if you can guarantee that every one of the `<name>...</name>` elements in your KML file always falls on a line by itself.