# extracting data from txt file?

Tags: dos, extract

Extract data from a text file, the file consists of the following, say:

```
<img src="a.jpg" alt="abc" height="12px" width="12px">
<div class="ab3" id="1122">
<img src="b.jpg" alt="abc" height="12px" width="12px">
<div class=cd5" id="9876">
```

I want to extract the "id" value from the above shown text file...
the output should be:

```
1122
9876
```

I tried using findstr, find etc(DOS-COMMANDS), but not able to find the perfect regular expression for the same,

any other way is there, any help?

Comment: Try using winGrep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @izogfif, you should consider some other tools for this task.

But, to answer what you asked for, I got this regex:

```
id="[0-9]+"
```

It will give you output like this:

```
id="1122"
id="9876"
```

From there you can save those results (or use a pipe, however you do that in DOS), and then this regex:

```
[0-9]*
```

Will give you this output:

```
1122
9876
```

Comment: thankyou sir, how should i use findstr....means i used t as findstr  regularexpressiontobeplacedhere "filename"..........how should i use regular expression here

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
( id=")[^"]*"
```

This will match any Id's value.

You can replace `id` with any attribute you are searching for.