# Extract magento events in windows from app directory

Tags: windows, magento, grep

In this [Magento help page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) I have seeen this commmand:

> grep -rin -B2 -A2 "Mage::dispatchEvent" app/* > events.txt

How I can do this via windows command line or .bat file? Or do you think it's easier done via php programming?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it via PHP Magento, but I wonder if it can be done via windows command line.

```
//Load Magento
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

//Get Config
//header('Content-Type: text/xml');         
header('Content-Type: text/plain');         
$config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('config.xml')->getNode('global/events');              
$events = $config[0];
foreach($events as $item){      
    echo $item->getName()." \n";
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but this doesnt' fetch all events. Only the used ones :-(

Answer (score 0):

there are grep for windows:
http://www.wingrep.com/

And a answered SO question: [What are good grep tools for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows)