# Search for phrases in docs in ClearCase

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, clearcase

I have a lot of docs in clearcase which are not properly sorted and I have to migrate them to Sharepoint after sorting them. I have the folder structer of how I want the docs to be sorted in sharePoint. Now I want to search for particular words in the docs in ClearCase and move that doc to the respective folder in Sharepoint. For example, if a doc contained the word "design" it is most likely to go into the design process folder in SharePoint. So I want to be able to search word phrases in the docs that are stored in ClearCase. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a ClearCase feature, but rather a simple grep issue.
(unless you want to search in all the versions of a ClearCase file)

I would recommend simply loading your docs in a [snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309), and [use your favorite grep tool on those files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87378/6309).

Comment: I'm gonna use UltraEdit. Thanks!