# is there any way to remove java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grep": CreateProcess error=2" in windows

Tags: java, linux

Program including following code works on ubuntu but i am not friendly with ubuntu. I want to make it work in windows. In windows it is showing exception as grep is not windows command.can it be solved??

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    //System.out.println(list.get(i));

    try{
    str="grep -c -w "+ list.get(i) +" 1.txt";   

    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);

BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    int line=Integer.parseInt(in1.readLine());

    if(line==0){
    b="0,".getBytes();
    out.write(b);       
    }

    else{
    b="1,".getBytes();
    out.write(b);       
    }

}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). Possible duplicate of [What are good grep tools for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/87350/2970947)

Comment: is `grep` a command/program that comes with linux?  what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install grep program for windows. Something like this http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [FindStr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true), a built in Windows equivalent to grep.