# How to see what code gets executed when you perform specific action in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

ExtJs TextArea has `maxLength` property. When `maxLength` property is used with `enforceMaxLength` property **it restrict the maximum number of characters that can be entered into the field**.

If I set `maxLength` property to 5 and `enforceMaxLength` to true, user is only allowed to enter 5 character. Even when you paste some string which is greater than 5 characters, text-area only allows 5 character and remaining characters are ignored.

Since we can see the CodeBase of ExtJS, I want to see the code, which does not allow user to enter more than 5 character in the scenario I explained earlier.

I looked at this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-cfg-maxLengthText) and clicked on view source which opened this [page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/Text3.html#Ext-form-field-Text-cfg-maxLength) but I am not able to figure out what code is getting executed for the above scenario.

I am more interested in learning how to trace back to the code which gets executed when user paste or type some text in ExtJs textarea.

I am using ExtJs 4.1. **Feel free to provide your feedback if the question does not make sense**

Comment: I've never tried to look inside maxLengthText propetry, but I've made a similar thing with the datepicker component; I was interesting to get know how to component works across the user interaction. I've examinated ext-all-dev.js file to investigate how the framework operates.

Comment: It sets the maxLength property on the underlying `textarea`. Most modern browsers support it. For those that don't it attempts catch the paste event and do other stuff.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: I am interested in seeing the code under paste event. How can i see it? I have tried using FireBug with profile option but no luck so far :(

Comment: `grep` the code for paste, you'll find it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: Can you please tell me in detail how to grep the code.

Comment: Linux and OS X have command-line `grep` command, you can get info on how to use it by typing `man grep`. For windows, see this discusson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows