# grep cf logs from windows machine

Tags: windows, logging, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I am using the CloudFoundry CLI tool to tail logs from a remote cloudfoundry server. As per the [cloud foundry log docs](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html) the command is

```
cf logs **app_name** --recent | grep RTR.
```

When i run this i get the error, grep is not recognized as a command. I believe this only works in a Unix based system. How can i use a grep like functionality from Windows CF CLI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good grep tools for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

```
cf logs app_name --recent | findstr RTR
```

> Findstr is capable of finding the exact text you are looking for in
>   any ASCII file or files. However, sometimes you have only part of the
>   information that you want to match, or you want to find a wider range
>   of information. In such cases, findstr has the powerful capability to
>   search for patterns of text using regular expressions.

[Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)

other solution would be that you install GNU grep on Windows. There are several ports available.

Comment: Thanks @fyodor78 . findstr didnt give an error but the search results are not accurate as say grep.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows command prompt does not natively support bash prior to Windows 10, which is required for commands like grep. To use grep, you either have to use the git-bash shell provided during a git install, or in current releases of Windows, use the bash command in a Windows Command Prompt after installing the Windows Linux Subsystem. [Windows Reference Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the git-bash if you have [git](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) installed on your machine. The git-bash comes with UNIX tools such as grep, so you would just open the git-bash instead of the Windows console and enter your command there.