# Golang 1.8: Embedded database for logging

Tags: logging, go

I am trying to find an embedded database for logging purposes in **golang**, as text file based logging is not best suited in windows (no cat, grep or xargs to save your day). So, I am looking for a solution, which will let me fire a query against my log file.

Can anyone please suggest me what solution I can deploy to make logging and MORE IMPORTANTLY, log viewing easy?

Comment: What do you mean with `embedded database`?

Answer (score 0):

A Embedded NoSql Database is what you want, i think.

[tiedot](https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot) looks interesting

otherwise if you want to try grep for windows ->

[what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows)