# Grep alternative in Windows

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, find

I have the command `grep public -A 5` in Unix which prints the trailing 5 lines after the string `public`.

I need to do the same in Windows using command prompt. How do I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/87350/1030675

Comment: the question has been closed as a duplicate although it is not the same of a question which was closed because not constructive

Comment: [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/689886/grep-with-context-about-matched-lines-in-windows) may be a better candidate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with powershell

```
powershell -command "Get-ChildItem *.* | Select-String 'public' -context 0,5"
```

where `*.*` is replaced with filename pattern