# Alternative to using findstr

Tags: windows, ping, findstr

TLDR: findstr and find are missing/not available. How else can I achieve the same result?

I'm trying to run the following command

`ping -n 1 %%a | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"`

To check if a host is pingable or not.
However the pc it is to run on has a custom XP install that does not have find nor findstr, what could I do?

Comment: You only have MSDOS emulation? How about WSL? PowerShell?

Comment: *"How else can I achieve the same result?"* Get a `grep` utility. See e.g. [What are good grep tools for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/87350/5221149)

Comment: No PowerShell nor WSL.
I cannot install any extra utilities.